# The properties of benign tumours

Tags: cancer, growth, apoptosis

Do benign tumours have no functioning apoptosis mechanisms ? If so what stops benign tumours from excessive growth? Also can a benign tumour have a functioning apoptosis mechanism?

Comment: To rephrase ; 'Does a benign tumour have no working apoptosis mechanism?' If they have no self-destruct mechanisms what stops them from excessive growth?

Comment: If a benign tumours genome is analyzed would this give clues as to how it has no functioning apoptosis mechanisms yet it doesn't grow or metastasize ?

Answer (score 2):

Benign tumors can absolutely have mechanisms available to them to commit to and carry out apoptosis.  An example of this would be benign prostatic hyperplasia, in which the balance of apoptotic and proliferating cells is offset, but apoptosis is still occurring, simply at a lower comparative rate than the proliferation.

Benign tumors can therefore be caused either by excessive proliferation or inadequate cell death; evidently, a complete failure of programmed cell death in many tissues would result in a tumor, benign or no.

---

#### Source:

- Kyprianou N, Tu H, Jacobs SC. Apoptotic versus proliferative activities in human benign prostatic hyperplasia.  Hum Pathol. 1996 Jul. 27(7): 668-75.